# SQL Query Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am an iOS Developer, and I have absolutely no experience with SQL Databases. However I am using the next query to fetch some info:

```
INSERT INTO search ( packageID )
    SELECT RowID
    FROM packages
    WHERE name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?
    ORDER BY %@ ASC
```

(That `%@` it's just an Objective-C NSString thing).

My question is, is there anyway to order the results making what has been returned from the first WHERE(`WHERE name LIKE ?`) be over the results returned by the second WHERE?

Thanks a lot and excuse my ignorance!

Comment: An `insert` doesn't return results, so you have made us all confused.

Comment: No, it inserts them into a table. But what returns is the WHERE.... Anyway as I said I'm just an iOS Developer :/

Comment: You can't specify a precedence on the where criteria, you can only order the result set returned.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz How could I do to order the results of the first WHERE with more priority than the ones from the second WHERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give one condition precedence over another, you can express that in the keys for the `order by`:

```
SELECT RowID
FROM packages
WHERE name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name LIKE ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
          %@ ASC  -- not sure if this is needed or desired
```

Do note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you really want a result set in this order then run the `SELECT` query.  Once in a table the ordering information is (theoretically) lost.

Comment: This works amazingly! You saved my day sir thanks a lot! :)